# looking for some script in PyVmomi

Tags: python, virtual-machine, vmware

I need to write python scripts to get all of the IDs of Virtual Machines running on a ESX/ESXi host(including CPU ID, Hard ID, Chipset ID etc.).i need to find them and i want to change them all.i have to move a virtual machine from one ESXi host to another ESXi host but when i move it the license of virtual machine get lost, i did some researches and i find the license get lost because of changing hardware fingerprint during the movement process. Could anyone please help me to solve this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of pyvmomi examples can be found [here](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples), on VMWare's own GitHub. Also, if you open an issue on the project in GitHub and request something specific, others in the community may be willing to provide it.

Answer (score -1):

Amir you can get examples here

https://github.com/rreubenur/vmware-python-examples

And losing the license is a common problem for windows VM. Though there is a hack for winxp/win2k3 but later versions doesn't support the hack. I believe you shouldn't face any problem with linux guest OS.